# Query post & loop problem.

Tags: loop, query

i having trouble while i added query to loop.

please have a look whats the problem.

[here is the link](http://www.news.shreshthbharat.in)

```
 <div class="fl" id="main_article">
 <?php $count = 1;
 $the_query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=headline&orderby=post_date&order=desc' );

    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while (have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();       if($count == 1) : ?>

 <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title=""><?php the_title(); ?></a>
 <?php dynamic_excerpt(400); ?>
 <?php else : ?>

 <div class="post">
 <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title=""><?php the_title(); ?></a>
 <?php dynamic_excerpt(400); ?>  </div>

 <?php if ($count== 2 || $count == 4 ){ ?>  

 <?php dynamic_sidebar('index-insert') ?>
 <?php } ?>
 <?php $count = $count + 0; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php $count++; ?> 
<?php endwhile; ?> </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no idea what the problems actually are, but from looking at the code, I woud suggest:

a:
the `while (have_posts()) :` should be `while ($the_query->have_posts()) :`

b:
you would need to increment the counter:
`<?php $count = $count + 1; ?>`

c:
the `endif;` of the loop might be missing after the `endwhile;` - at least it is not shown in the posted code section.

Comment: thanks for your reply !! done here is the  <?php $count = 1;
$the_query = new WP_Query('category_name=headline&orderby=post_date&order=desc'); 
        if ($the_query->have_posts()) :?>
<?php while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); if($count == 1) : ?>

Comment: what is or was the actual problem with the code?